# Flutter firebase version solving error arise after using firebase auth and firebase core dependencies

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-web, flutter-test

I'm having this issue when I've added firebase_auth dependency in my flutter project. Can anyone please help me with it?

[image]

dependencies:

```
  cached_network_image: ^2.2.0+1
  provider: ^4.3.2
  firebase_core: ^0.4.5
  velocity_x: ^0.4.1
  flushbar: ^1.10.4
  firebase_auth: ^0.16.1
  flutter_dropdown: ^0.0.7+hotfix.1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
You can use the following version:

firebase_core: ^0.4.4+3                
firebase_auth: ^0.16.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Please run

```
flutter doctor -v
```

If it is stable channel then use those dependencies. Firebase cause conflict if they are not properly configure.

```
  firebase_auth: ^0.15.4
  firebase_core: ^0.4.3+3
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing to dev channel worked out for me.